Hyperjaxb3 wrong jpa relationship
My xsd ,as in attached file , report a relation ROOT 1-->1 Header but when I build project using  the hyperjaxb3 it create a wrong @ManyToOne annotation than @OneToOne as the xsd have a default sequence constraint ( 1 ) :
Code created is :
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = HeaderType.class, cascade = {
CascadeType.ALL
})
@joincolumn(name = "HEADER_ROOT_HJID")
public HeaderType getHeader() {

Excerpt from XSD :

Excerpt literal from XSD (for rick)
<xs:element name="ROOT">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="Header" type="tns:HeaderType" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Data_Block" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Sensing_Start_Time" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="Sensing_Stop_Time" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="List_of_Acquisitions" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="Acquisition" type="tns:AcquisitionType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="count" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="List_Of_Dumps" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="Dump" type="tns:DumpType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="count" use="required"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


HiSrc HyperJAXB Maven Plugin generates the @ManyToOne JPA annotation when a source entity references a single target entity. This is the intended behavior. In absence of other information, this choice provides a foreign reference without inferring ownership. When ownership is present then the target entity's life cycle is bound to the source which is a much stronger choice.
Of course, your design can choose to apply ownership to this type of relationship, when it is appropriate. To generate a @OneToOne relationship, you can define this JAXB binding:
RootHeader.xjb
...
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='Root']//xs:element[@name='header']">
    <hj:one-to-one>
        <!-- Optional, custom column name.
        <orm:join-column name="HEADER_ROOT_HJID"/>
        -->
    </hj:one-to-one>
</jaxb:bindings>
...

The above binding is applied on the target header element using a customization from the HyperJAXB namespace. Optionally, you can use the orm namespace to customize the database column that JPA uses to join the source entity, Root, to the target entity, Header; otherwise, HyperJAXB will choose an appropriate column name to represent the join.
The JAXB binding file, RootHeader.xjb, is applied to your XML schema file RootHeader.xsd to generate the JAXB/JPA entities. These classes are generated to target/generated-sources/xjc/org/example/root_header/ and included in the classpath.
Execution
After downloading this demo (zip) and extracting it to a local folder, you can run the test and/or application using either of two JPA providers:

Note: This demo is a stand-alone Maven project.

Eclipselink
mvn -Peclipselink clean test
mvn -Peclipselink clean compile exec:java

or
Hibernate
mvn -Phibernate clean test
mvn -Phibernate clean compile exec:java

This output shows the test results using Hibernate.
Persistence: H2 or PostgreSQL
By default, this project uses a local H2 database. The H2 database is automatically created when the application creates its EntityManagerFactory.
Alternatively, this project can be re-configured to use your own PostgreSQL database server.
Approach
The hisrc-hyperjaxb-maven-plugin is configured to generate JPA/JAXB classes using the provided RootHeader.xsd schema. The schema provides the namespace "http://org.example/root_header" which JAXB uses to create the Java package name using its own naming convention.
As the default option, a more advanced implementation of Java's built-in Object methods are generated using these XJC hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins. In particular, the sample project uses the toString plugin to display human-readable representations of the unmarshaled Root objects.

Note: The hisrc-hyperjaxb-maven-plugin extends the hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin but pre-configures several of the XJC hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins; thus, the hisrc-basicjaxb-runtime dependency is required on the run-time class path. For more help on the configuration details, see ...

mvn hisrc-hyperjaxb:help -Ddetail=true

Testing
The JUnit test class, RoundtripTest.java, scans for the sample files and invokes the method super.checkSample(File samle) to provide each file to the tester. For this project, an EntityManagerFactory and a JAXBContext are created and each file in the samples path is:

unmarshaled to an initial Root object
unmarshaled to an etalon Root object
A JPA transaction is started.

The initial object is merged into the persistence session


The JPA transaction is committed
A new JPA EntityManager, em, instance is created

The new em is used to load the persisted Root by id
The etalon, merged and loaded Root objects are compared for equality


The em is closed and each Root object is marshaled for review in the logs

When successful, each object is marshaled for logging and your review.
Demonstration
A Java standard engine application with a main(...) method is at org.example.root_header.Main. This application is executed using:
mvn -Peclipselink clean compile exec:java -Dexec.args="src/test/samples/root-header-01.xml"
OR
mvn -Phibernate   clean compile exec:java -Dexec.args="src/test/samples/root-header-01.xml"

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the HiSrc projects.

Rick ,then your example is working ,producing @OneToOne, as for XJB bindings or (more correct than mine)  XSD ? In other words , I didn't understand what you mean as

Yes, the demo provided produces the @OntToOne annotation in the generated Java class. Do a download and give it a go!

I have included your XSD into the demo (zip) and declared the one-to-one annotation on the HeaderType element in the XSD, itself. The demo generates the @OneToOne annotation in the JAXB class, ROOT on the HeaderType getter.

As complement of answer of Rick, you can find the following from highsource original documentation (which will be backported in the github wiki in jaxb-tools)
https://web.archive.org/web/20150929032052/http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Reference+-+single+page
EDIT (new link) : https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/HyperJAXB3-Reference-Single-Page#mapping-as-one-to-one

Mapping as one-to-one
You can use the hj:one-to-one customization element to map your complex single property as @OneToOne instead of @ManyToOne :

From sample here (see header declaration of prefixes)
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"

    xmlns:hj="urn:hyperjaxb3.jvnet.org:ejb:schemas:customizations"
    xmlns:orm="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/orm"

<xs:element name="one-to-one-join-column" type="test:three" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <hj:one-to-one>
                <orm:join-column name="O2OJC_THREE_ID"/>
            </hj:one-to-one>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>

This will generate expected @OneToOne relation between JPA entities with code like below :
@XmlElement(name = "one-to-one-join-column")
protected Three oneToOneJoinColumn;
 
@OneToOne(targetEntity = Three.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.ALL
})
@JoinColumn(name = "O2OJC_THREE_ID")
public Three getOneToOneJoinColumn() {
    return oneToOneJoinColumn;
}
 
public void setOneToOneJoinColumn(Three value) {
    this.oneToOneJoinColumn = value;
}


ok this is solution through JAXB Binding XJB file , but I would know if there is a problem in XSD file that prevent to have normally ( without xjb custom file) a @OneToOne annotation

Your choice,  you can declare the one-to-one annotation either in the xjb or in-line in the xsd file. The xsd file is fine.

@rick   I already declared it in xsd :  <xs:element name="Header" type="tns:HeaderType" maxOccurs="1"/>  even if it is not mandatory , maxOccurs=1 is the default , it correct ?  then ,although this , I got ManyToOne !

ManyToOne just says that the Header type could be referenced by many ROOT elements, there's no way hyperjaxb3 knows that it's 1<->1 relationship.
If you would have set maxOccurs=unbounded, I guess it would have generated a ManyToMany relationship.

@KronosOne : added new link to documentation :)

Guys , ok I know bindings feature ,but my question is : since in my XSD I have the constraint as  ROOT <--1 to 1 -->HEADER , Why I cannot get the correct JPA annotation normally,  whithout use of bindings ?

Your xsd only describes the relationship in one way : the root element only have one header but one header can be pointed by many roots. If I can use root as image metadata and header is file format, one metadata as only one file format (jpg, png, ...) but one fileformat can be used by many metadata, so header here is OneToMany relation with Root and so Root does have ManyToOne relationship in java generated file. If you know that it's one-to-one only, you can precise it using bindings as explained. Feel free to ask if need more info
